# JAVA System.out.println equation

Tags: java

Can someone explain to me why the following code prints the char 'u' ?

```
 int p = 9;
 int q = 5;
 int r = p - q;
 double x = p;
 double y = q;
 String s = "Question";

 System.out.println ((char)(s.charAt(r) + 1));
```

Comment: Because `charAt(4)`  is `t` (int value 116), and `u` has an int value of 117 (116+1).

Comment: What did you expect it to print out, and why? note that you don't use `x` or `y`.

Comment: I'm revising for an exam and the question was giving me the print.ln statement and I had to work out what it was printing

Comment: you actually working with `ASCII` in this example of yours .

Answer (score 3):

1) `p-q = 4`

2) character at index `4` is `t` (`s.chartAt(4)` gives character at index `4` in string `s`).

3) you have added `1` to it so `1` was added to its ASCII value making the ASCII value equal to ASCII value of `u`.

4) then the integer was cast to char which will be `'u'`, which was printed.

Answer (score 2):

Because `s.charAt(r)` = `'t'` and `'t'` as int is 116. 116 + 1 is 117 and 117 as char is `u`;

If you split up the oneliner it might be more clear:

```
char charAtR = s.charAt(r);
int plusOne = charAtR + 1; // char will be converted to int
char toPrint = (char) plusOne;

System.out.println (toPrint);
```

Answer (score 1):

You take `char` at position `4` (since `r` is `p - q`, which is `4`) in string `s`, and its `t`. In `s.charAt('t')` you take its `char` value (ASCII code), which is `116`, and you add `1` to it, so you will `117`, which is ASCII code of `u` and you turn it in char, so it will print `u`.

For example, if you do this:

```
String s = "Question";
System.out.println((int)s.charAt(r));
```

It will print `116`. If you do this:

```
 String s = "Question";
 System.out.println((char) 177);
```

It prints `u`.

If you're wondering why is `t` at position `4`, and not `s`, thats because `charAt` works from `0`, not from `1`.

Answer (score 1):

In `System.out.println()` you receive character `'t'` from string `"Question"` and output next codePoint that is `'u'`.

Answer (score 0):

The value of **r** is **4**. Therefore,

```
s.charAt(r); = s.charAt(4); = ELEMENT AT 4th INDEX OF "Question" = 't'
```

When an integer is added to a char (`eg. 'A'+1`) or the **post increment operator** is used with a char (`eg. char_variable++`), the **ASCII** value of the char is incremented.
So,

```
s.charAt(r)+1 = (char)((ASCII value of 't')+1) = (char)(116+1) = 'u'
```

Since 117 is the ASCII value of 'u', the program displays 'u'.